# Ant JUnit throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, junit, ant, travis-ci

I am developing a Java application in IntelliJ IDE. In order to be able to connect my repo to Travis CI, I came through generating ant build.xml using my IDE. However IntelliJ haven't created test target in the build file. I have manually edited it by adding the following:

```
<target name="test" depends="compile.module.pearplanner.tests">
    <junit>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="./Test/">
                <include name="**/*Test*" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

When I run

```
ant test
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
test:
[junit] Testsuite: Model.AccountTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] 
[junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
[junit] Model.AccountTest
[junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Model.AccountTest
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[junit] 
[junit] 
[junit] Test Model.AccountTest FAILED
[junit] Testsuite: Model.PersonTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] 
[junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
[junit] Model.PersonTest
[junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Model.PersonTest
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[junit] 
[junit] 
[junit] Test Model.PersonTest FAILED
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zc76.png)

I have tested multiple approaches I could find on the web, but all of them were giving me the same output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are your classes which needs to be tested? Add that to the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. Turned out that I had to specify class output directory and test class output directory in the classpath. Also hamcrest-core-1.3.jar wasn't there either. Correct version:

```
<target name="test" depends="build.modules" >
    <junit haltonerror="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${pearplanner.output.dir}/"/>
            <pathelement location="${pearplanner.testoutput.dir}/"/>
        </classpath>
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${pearplanner.testoutput.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test*" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```